# Create Permutations and Combinations of List in Python (Efficiently)

Tags: python, python-2.7, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I want to create a list that contains every permutation of various combinations of elements satisfying a certain condition. Specifically, I want every list of a given length consisting of mostly zeros with either one or two differing elements, either of which can be a 1 or -1. I have written the following, which works, but is slow:

```
import itertools
slots = 12
all_choices = []
for elements in itertools.product(*[[-1,0,1] for ii in range(slots)]):
  if sum([abs(ii) for ii in elements]) in [1, 2]:
    all_choices.append(list(elements))
```

I managed to make it a little faster like this:

```
slots = 12
all_choices = []
for first in [-1, 1]:
  for second in [-1, 1]:
    for ii in range(slots):
      for jj in range(ii, slots):
        choices = [0 for kk in range(slots)]
        choices[ii] = first
        choices[jj] = second
        if choices not in all_choices:
          all_choices.append(choices)
```

But this still feels pretty clunky and I'm sure there is a more efficient/cleaner way to utilize `itertools` to get what I am after. Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Creating all desired changes (from an all-zero list) and applying them:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def all_choices(slots, maxchanges=2):
    for k in range(1, maxchanges+1):
        for I in combinations(range(slots), k):
            for V in product([-1, 1], repeat=k):
                elements = [0] * slots
                for i, v in zip(I, V):
                    elements[i] = v
                yield elements
```

For example `print(*all_choices(3))` prints this:

```
[-1, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0] [0, -1, 0] [0, 1, 0] [0, 0, -1] [0, 0, 1] [-1, -1, 0] [-1, 1, 0] [1, -1, 0] [1, 1, 0] [-1, 0, -1] [-1, 0, 1] [1, 0, -1] [1, 0, 1] [0, -1, -1] [0, -1, 1] [0, 1, -1] [0, 1, 1]
```

Note the `maxchanges` parameter, lets you easily request different number of changes.